# How to handle Iframe errors in React

Tags: reactjs

Here I have two components, let's call them parent components and child components, the picture looks like this:

Parent component :

```
import { Card, Col, Row } from "antd";


import PDFcomponent from "../../../components/PdfView/index"

function Index({data}) {
    
    return (
     <>
       <Row>
         <Col>

           <Col className="pdf">
             <PDFcomponent data={data} />
           </Col>
        
               <Col className="content">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>This is content</p>
               </Col>
        
                
         </Col>
       </Row>
         </>
        );
}

export default Index;
```

Then the "PDFcomponent" component display is like this:

```
import { Col } from "antd";
import UrlPDF from "./document";

function PdfComponent ({ data }) {
   
    return (
        <Col className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
            
            <Iframe
                height="500"
                url=""
                width="500"
            />
        </Col>
    );
}

export default PdfComponent;
```

Here I have a problem, namely, when the component "PDFcomponent" errors, everything in the parent component becomes an error.

I want when there is a problem or error in the contents of the "PDFcomponent" component, the parent displays an error message, for example:

```
<Col className="pdf">
   <PDFcomponent data={data} />

   <div> <p>An error occurred with the PDF</p> </div> ===> Show if "PDFcomponent" error occurs in it
</Col>
```

So, when an error occurs in the "PDFcomponent" all the parts in the parent component have no impact on the error that occurs

Comment: Can you define more on what and how can the `<PDFcomponent />` errors out?

Comment: What I mean here is, all errors that might occur in the "PDFcomponent" so that it affects all the content in the parent component, for example if the URL in it is wrong url="invalid-url"

How do I do it if the "PDFcomponent" error occurs, all the content in the parent component is not affected by the error that occurred?

Can it be overcome?

Comment: I definitely dont think it works like that, you should have maybe a url validator, and if the url is invalid, then renders something else besides the `<iframe />` You can use conditional rendering for this.

Comment: My point is that, you'll have to know what kind of error you want to catch, and add validator accordingly to catch those errors.